# Creating Eventbridge Scheduler to Trigger Glue Data Quality Ruleset runs in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

On the AWS console, we are able to schedule AWS Glue Data Quality ruleset runs by defining either the schedule in editing settings for the Ruleset (which automatically creates EventBridge Scheduler schedules) or by manually creating the EventBridge scheduler ourselves and calling the DataQualityRuleRecommendationRun API with a custom payload.

I want to be able to accomplish the same goal but using AWS CDK to create the resources necessary for scheduling of AWS Glue Data Quality rulesets. How do I go about accomplishing this?

The (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_glue.CfnDataQualityRuleset.html) CFN object does not have a schedule attribute similar to the AWS Console.

This leads me to believe that (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_scheduler.CfnSchedule.html) should be where I can create the scheduling resource for the DataQualityRuleset. On the documentation page, it even mentions that it supports universal targets for over 6000 services however, taking a look at the (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_scheduler.CfnSchedule.TargetProperty.html) I don't see the parameters necessary to do so.

So, how do I accomplish the goal of creating a scheduling option for a AWS Glue Data Quality ruleset? It's highly preferred to use the above, or related, resources, and not have to resort to using other services, such as Lambda.